# Only deliver batch error emails to one admin

Tags: email, batch

I'm debugging a batch in our sandbox, and it's blasting all of the Admin users with an error email for each chunk:

> Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.

Until I solve that little problem (I have no idea where it is coming from) I would like to prevent future test runs from sending emails to all admins in the org.

How do I do that?

EDIT: It is important to note that the batch chunks complete successfully, there are no errors in the actual batch.

Also, this has nothing to do with Apex Exception Email in settings, because that list only contains a single email address, not all 6 admins that are being bombarded with emails.

Comment: Well, after delving into code written by the other devs in the org, it turns out that there is a batch being called from the trigger which needs to be disabled before running another batch. Furthermore, that function call is what sends the email, so it is our code sending the email not Salesforce. >:|

Comment: This whole question was a misunderstanding of my own org. Not sure whether I should answer it or delete it...